# Angular2: second index.html, 2 apps in 1 project

Tags: angular

Is possible to add 1 more html file in project?
For example:
index.html and partner.html?
Its not a component, its like another app, but i would like to use it in one project.

Second file should work on url: http://localhost:4200/partner.html

Comment: I don't have the answer to your question... It could be possible... but if you're using the angular cli (or some other build tool) then there will be some stuff inserted in your index.html to tell it where to load the bundled js ie: <script type="text/javascript" src="inline.462df87e52df7ff64188.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.80fc34279f44b5d76054.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.7aad2f45bf0422659f36.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.662ff06fb7c78358e012.bundle.js"></script></body>

Comment: So unless you can get it to insert those same scripts I don't think there would be an automated way... You could of course do it manually.